# Stata: Reducing observations based on yearly data

Tags: stata

I want to create a variable that is one or zero if a company (`companyid` below) is "multicolor" in each year. Below is my data:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str6 companyid int year float(red blue green)
"001045" 2015 0 1 0
"001045" 2015 0 1 0
"001045" 2015 0 1 0
"001045" 2015 0 1 0
"001045" 2017 1 0 0
"001045" 2017 1 0 0

"001049" 2019 0 1 0
"001049" 2019 0 0 1

"001055" 2018 1 0 0
"001055" 2018 0 1 0
"001055" 2018 0 0 1
```

So for example, company #001055 is red, blue, and green for 2018 so this 'multicolor' variable should equal to one.

Additionally, I also want to create variables for the different combinations. I.e. a red-blue var = 1 if a company is red and blue = 1 in each year.

I was trying to do something with `bysort companyid year: gen multicolor = 1 if red == 1 & blue == 1 & green == 1` but I realize that has a lot missing in what I want to accomplish.

The overall goal is to reduce multiple year observations so I have one observation per year per company.

This single year/company record would have the info if that company was red, green, blue, or the exact mix of these colors if it is mixed. Below would be the example of data that I want to create from the data above.

```
input str6 companyid int year float(red blue green r-b-g red-blue blue-green ...more...)
"001045" 2015 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
"001045" 2017 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
"001049" 2019 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
"001055" 2018 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a lot easier than you are fearing. First, `collapse` to maximum values by company and year. Then you have the individual values of `red blue green`. Second,  concatenate the values, so that `"110"` is red and blue but not green, and so on.

`tabulate` would generate all the indicators corresponding to combinations found in the data.

In effect, the 3 colors and 2 possibilities permit binary encoding, and the string is a binary number too.

The correspondence for true 1 and false 0 that maximum over 0s and 1s means "any" and that minimum over 0s and 1s means "all" is obvious once understood, but worth explaining otherwise. For a Stata context, see [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/)

```
clear
input str6 companyid int year float(red blue green)
"001045" 2015 0 1 0
"001045" 2015 0 1 0
"001045" 2015 0 1 0
"001045" 2015 0 1 0
"001045" 2017 1 0 0
"001045" 2017 1 0 0
"001049" 2019 0 1 0
"001049" 2019 0 0 1
"001055" 2018 1 0 0
"001055" 2018 0 1 0
"001055" 2018 0 0 1
end 

collapse (max) red blue green, by(companyid year) 

egen colors = concat(red blue green)

list

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     | compan~d   year   red   blue   green   colors |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. |   001045   2015     0      1       0      010 |
  2. |   001045   2017     1      0       0      100 |
  3. |   001049   2019     0      1       1      011 |
  4. |   001055   2018     1      1       1      111 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answered. Although that is pretty much exactly what I need, but with collapse I lose my other unrelated variables in the process. I guess I could save the colors var and the identifiers and merge it back to the original dataset, but maybe you know of a better solution than that?

Comment: Come on: the question says that you want the data reduced as specified! You could of course `collapse` any other variables in any way you want, but if the dataset is one observation per company and year, that is the most you can do. But sure, `merge` it back if need be. Or, contrary to the spirit of your question: the `collapse` isn't really what you want; then `egen` to get max and min and concatenate the results. Then values are repeated for all observations with the same company and year.